# ASP.NET update panel timer is not working automatically when internet connection is restored

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I am using `<asp:Timer />` outside of an update panel in ASP.NET Webforms and everything is working fine but when I disconnect internet connection, the timer stopped and I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Sys.WebForms.Res is undefined
> _createPageRequestManagerServerError
> _onFormSubmitCompleted

[image: Error shown in the image]

When internet connection is restored again, the timer is not working anymore, and I need to refresh the whole page manually - then it is working.

Browser console shows the error as in the image.

Please help me with this.

Comment: We kind of need to see what that timer is doing. If that timer not interacting with the panel, then it should continue to run, but it looks like there are more moving parts to this question - so we need to see what the timer does.  You might want to use JUST JavaScript code to run that timer, and if it not doing anything in regard to the u-panel, then you might be fine. The update panel if posting back does run a standard page cycle - including that of triggering the page on-load event. So, u-panels don't prevent post backs and server round trips - they only hide them.

Comment: timer is working fine until internet connection is there, when internet connection is gone and after connection restored then it causing problem.
It does not automatically run, I have to refresh the page to work it properly.
Is there any way that I don't need to refresh the page manually ?

Comment: If the Timer not Triggering the update panel,  then you may well be OK. Is the user logged in, and fid they have an active session? As noted this depends on a boatload of issues. We need to see what that Timer does- if that update panel is posting back then you likely have to remove it or ensure it not Triggering